# org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:

Tags: java, spring-security

I am getting the following error when I'm running the code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.1. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.1 schema.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
```

### at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)

The classes that I am using are

```
spring-security.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="admin" password="roseindia" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest you all to follow simple approach like never mentioned the xsd versions in **security.xml** and **application-servlet.xml** file, When you changes the versions of Spring Framework or Spring Security Framework there is always a possibility of getting such erros.

Just use following
spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="admin" password="roseindia" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spring-security xsd declaration is referring to Spring Security 3.0 and you are using Spring Security 3.1. Update your configuration as shown to use the 3.1.x version of Spring Security Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```